# Allow NodeJS to only control certain directories

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a cloud-computing project within Node.JS and I can't seem to figure out a good way to restrict the directory that Node.JS instance can control. How can I start a NodeJS application (via a child process) and restrict the directory NodeJS has access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict the server at the OS level, you need to create a Linux/Windows user, and give them access to only certain directories, and then run your Node.js process as that user. If you're talking about application-level users, then that is going to be 100% up to the logic of your application.

Comment: Awesome, so perhaps I can just create an OS user upon registration, and launch the child process as it.

Comment: Do you know anywhere that says how to launch a child process as another user? Preferably for both windows and linux, as I'll be moving to Linux upon production.

Comment: When a process spawns, you can use `setegid` or `seteuid` to set the owner. See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setegid_id). I don't think its possible to that on Windows though, works only for POSIX.

Comment: Alright, looks like I'm moving to a Unix server! Thanks ^_^